# how to add gridview image to linearlayout in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-linearlayout

i want to add a images to grid view and then to linear layout.i tried below code

```
    protected LinearLayout asLayout(final String message,final String path,boolean back){
    LoaderImageView liv=new LoaderImageView(this,path);
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100,120));
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    (imageView).setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    liv.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);




         linearWrapper = new GridView(mContext);

    linearWrapper.addView(asLayout(fmsg,fpath,true));
            linearWrapper.addView(asLayout(smsg,spath,false));  
        linerLayout.addView(linearWrapper);
```

the gridview was added but the images in grid view are not added .so please tell me the solution to how to add the gridview images to linearlayout.

Thanks in advance

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need an adapter for the grid view. Look at  [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) to learn how to add adapters.

Edit 1: Sample code:

```
public class TestGrid extends Activity {
   int[] myImages;
   @Override public void OnCreate(Bundle icicle) {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      GridView mGridView = new GridView(this);
      /** Set up your data array with resource id's from your app. */
      setAdapter(new TestAdapter());

      setContentView(mGridView);
   }

   private class BenchAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override public int getCount() { return (mContent != null) ?  myImages.length : -1; }
    @Override public Object getItem(int pos) { return pos; }
    @Override public long getItemId(int pos) { return pos; }
    @Override public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
       if (myImages == null) return null;
       GridView.LayoutParams lp = null;
       if (getWidth() < getHeight()) lp = new GridView.LayoutParams(getWidth()/3, getHeight()/2);
       else lp = new GridView.LayoutParams(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/3);

       ImageView iv = new ImageView(TestGrid.this);
       iv.setBackgroundResource(myImages[pos]);
       iv.setLayoutParams(lp); 

       return iv;
      }
}
```

Now what this will do is set a gridview as the activities content view. The Adapter will fill the content of the gridview. Without the adapter, the gridview would have no idea of what it should display.

Comment: I have a similar doubt too. why would I need an adapter? adapters still confuse me.

Comment: Adapters are fantastic little things that make some widgets easier to use. The main purpose of adapters is to organize the data for widgets such as the gridview and gallery etc.... They aren't to complicated if you want to do some simple stuff with them. All update my answer with a sample that should help.